# $\mathbb{P}(S<\infty)=0$ where S is the sum of independent RVs $X_1, X_2, \dots$ distributed exp$(\lambda_n)$ with $0 < \lambda_n \leq 1$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ are independent RVs such that $X_n$ ~ exp$(\lambda_n)$ with $0 < \lambda_n \leq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Defining $S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$

I am trying to prove $P(S<M)=0$ for all $M>0$.

It seems obviously right, I am trying to use the harmonic sum to prove it though I'm quite struggling with the formality.

Comment: How does expected value of $X_n$ depend on $\lambda_n$?

Comment: What is the distribution of $X_n$ if $\lambda_n=0$?

Comment: @drhab it shouldn't be 0 inclusive I will edit

Comment: @NCh It is $1/\lambda_n$ but some puzzle part is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every fixed positive integer $k$ we have: $$\left\{ S<M\right\} \subseteq\bigcap_{n=1}^{k}\left\{ X_{n}<M\right\} $$
so that:$$P\left(S<M\right)\leq P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{k}\left\{ X_{n}<M\right\} \right)=\prod_{n=1}^{k}P\left(X_{k}<M\right)=\prod_{n=1}^{k}\left(1-e^{-\lambda_{n}M}\right)\leq\left(1-e^{-M}\right)^{k}$$

Here $1-e^{-M}\in(0,1)$ so that for every $\epsilon>0$ we can find a $k$ with $\left(1-e^{-M}\right)^{k}<\epsilon$.

This proves that the $P(S<M)$ must have value $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Start by understanding the problem.

$$\forall_{M>0} \ \  \mathbb{P}(S\ge M)=1 \ \iff \ \mathbb{P}(S=\infty)=1. $$

Note that if $X_{n}\sim \exp(\lambda_{n}) \ $  with $\lambda_{n} \in (0,1)\ $, then
$$\mathbb{P}(X_{n}>1)=e^{-\lambda_{n}}\ge e^{-1}.$$

Now, since all $\ X_{n} \ $ are independent and 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X_{n}>1)=+\infty,$$
then by Borel-Cantelli lemma 
$$\mathbb{P}\Big(X_{n}>1 \ \ \ \ \text{for infinitely many} \  \ \ \ n \Big)=1,$$
which trivialy implies postulated thesis.